# Excel VBA: Worksheet change event triggered needlessly and unable to handle multiple changes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that acts upon changes in 4 columns of a table in Excel. My problem can be divided in two:

**First and the most important:** the columns I track changes were added to a table that comes from a database query. It works fine, mostly, until the query is refreshed. Then, I believe since the table is refreshed it triggers the Change Event. I have tried running the code piece by piece, and I saw that the change event returns a lot of changes,some null, which throws TYPE MISMATCH error in `If (Target.Value) = "Other" Then`. I tried adding a condition like `If not IsNull(Target.Value) = "Other"` but it does not work.

I am not sure how to fix this, I don't think disabling the Worksheet_Change event while refreshing will work because the TYPE MISMATCH errors are thrown AFTER the query is refreshed.

Is there an option to tell Excel to execute the code only on user made changes? Or a way to avoid this mismatch error after the query is refreshed other than separating the columns from the queried table?

**Second:** An example of what I do is, if the user writes a numeric amount greater than 1 in the column "QTY", rows are added. But if the user writes a number, and then fills down, the code just runs for the first change. It does not run for the other changes, instead it throws, guess what, a mismatch error. The Change event does register the changes, but only the first change passes through the first `Intersect` with a value, the other changes go through with empty values.

EXAMPLE:

I have a table like this. If the user writes a number greater than 1 (x) in column QTY then (x - 1) rows will be inserted under the row where the change occurred.

```
**ID    COMPANY     LOCATION  DIVISION      FACT**   QTY    REASON
1   FROOT CO    US         FROOT        FR132        2    Other
2   EA          EUROPE     GAME         EA2342            Other
3   TESLA       CHINA      ELECTRONIC   TE2542          
4   TWITTER     SPAIN      SOCIAL       TW432       
5   FACEBOOK    CANADA     SOCIAL       FB0424
```

Final output:

```
**ID    COMPANY     LOCATION  DIVISION      FACT**   QTY    REASON
1   FROOT CO    US         FROOT        FR132             Other
1   FROOT CO    US         FROOT        FR132             Other
2   EA          EUROPE     GAME         EA2342            Other
3   TESLA       CHINA      ELECTRONIC   TE2542          
4   TWITTER     SPAIN      SOCIAL       TW432       
5   FACEBOOK    CANADA     SOCIAL       FB0424
```

If the user writes a number at the time, the code works perfectly. But if he writes a number, and fills down before pressing enter, then the code gives a mismatch error.

Here the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim xValue As Integer
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableQuery")

On Error Resume Next
If Intersect(Target, tbl.ListColumns("Qty").Range, tbl.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    If Intersect(Target, tbl.ListColumns("Reason delay 1").Range, tbl.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        If Intersect(Target, tbl.ListColumns("Reason delay 2").Range, tbl.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
            If Intersect(Target, tbl.ListColumns("Reason delay 3").Range, tbl.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End If

On Error GoTo 0


If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
    If (Target.Value) < 2 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = ""
        Target.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    If (Target.Value) = "Other" Then
        Set KeyCells = Target.Offset(0, 1)
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="WowSoSecure123"
        KeyCells.Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="WowSoSecure123"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

xValue = Target.Value - 1

Set KeyCells = Intersect(Target.EntireRow, tbl.DataBodyRange)

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="WowSoSecure123"
Application.EnableEvents = False
Target.Value = ""
With KeyCells
    .Copy
    .Offset(1).Resize(xValue).Insert xlShiftDown
End With
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="WowSoSecure123"
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Target.Select

ExitHandler:
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="WowSoSecure123"
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance, if you need more info please tell me. I will provide. If you don't know a solution to my problem, but have suggestions to improve the code, please feel free to speak out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It can be tricky to troubleshoot someone else's version of someone else's code, especially without all the related information, such as: _what are you starting with? sample data? pictures of forms or relevant parts of worksheets? what are you trying to accomplish?  what should it look like when it's done?  what have you tried, where have you searched?  Exactly what errors are occurring where?" _  Check out the [S.O. Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well as these handy tips: [ask]

Comment: I am not really sure if you are a bot or not.

Comment: In a former life, perhaps.:)  Not a bot but I do share similar comments with new members whenever possible.  This site is different from another forums a in a lot of ways, and there can be a bit of a learning curve getting used to the in's and out's of question-asking "etiquette" here.  There is an amazing amount of knowledge & talent on this site, some members have been around for a _long_ time, and some can be kinda growly with new members who could have done more homework or given a more clear picture of what their issue is. The rules aren't obvious so I try to jump in sometimes and say Hi!

Comment: @ashleedawg alright. I think the problem in this case is that I gave too much information. Really, what I want is the Event Change to not be triggered after a refresh all in the queried table. Still, I will provide examples as soon as possible, I can't at the moment. And I will definitely read the guide you gave me.

Comment: ...but you want the event to fire _every_ other time cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link, correct?

Comment: Check out the [QueryTable.BeforeRefresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-beforerefresh-event-excel) event.  Perhaps you could have a public boolean variable, like `runChangeEvent`, and set it to False in the BeforeRefresh event, and then at the beginning of your Change event, check if runChangeEvent=False.  If so, set it to True and immediate exit the Change event sub.

Comment: Yes. That is what I want. What I added about the inserting rows is a bit confusing, I will give an example as soon as I can.

Comment: I added an example, I am still searching how to use the before refresh event, there are so many ways and some of them don't work.